# printf format float with padding

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

The following test code produces an undesired output, even though I used a width parameter:

```
int main(int , char* [])
{
    float test = 1234.5f;
    float test2 = 14.5f;

    printf("ABC %5.1f DEF\n", test);
    printf("ABC %5.1f DEF\n", test2);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
ABC 1234.5 DEF   
ABC  14.5 DEF
```

---

How to achieve an output like this, which format string to use?

```
ABC 1234.5 DEF   
ABC   14.5 DEF
```

Comment: This looks like c, not c++. Did you intend to tag c++?

Comment: @hmjd: My real code is C++, but this example is pure C. So you are right, I try to retag it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The following should line everything up correctly:

```
printf("ABC %6.1f DEF\n", test);
printf("ABC %6.1f DEF\n", test2);
```

When I run this, I get:

```
ABC 1234.5 DEF
ABC   14.5 DEF
```

The issue is that, in `%5.1f`, the `5` is the number of characters allocated for the entire number, and `1234.5` takes more than five characters. This results in misalignment with `14.5`, which does fit in five characters.

Comment: @nabulke: Yes, every character counts.

Answer (score 17):

You're trying to print something wider than 5 characters, so make your length specifier larger:

```
printf("ABC %6.1f DEF\n", test);
printf("ABC %6.1f DEF\n", test2);
```

The first value is not "digits before the point", but "total length".

Comment: Note that if you have a chance of printing infinity or Nan, you may want to provide more space after the decimal (at least 4 characters).  Then it becomes something like: `printf("ABC %10.4f DEF\n", test);`